# how to shift numbers in an array to be in descending order?

Tags: java, arrays, shift

Im writing a program which takes in user inputted digits to store as a high score table, the user decides how many numbers on the table, and then they type the numbers they want to appear on the table, although for some reason my code for putting the numbers on the table doesnt put the numbers in descending order as id like. I think it may be a problem with the for loops in the printHighScores function although i dont see how its wrong, it should keep comparing the numbers to see if theyre all in descending order but i think i may have made a mistake int he for loop operations...

My code inputs the size of the array, then it takes the numbers in and stores them accordingly in their array position, although it doesnt do the computation to store them in descending order?
If the user types the size of the array as 3, and inputs 100, 150, 433, I want the code to sort that so that it outputs

1. 433
2. 150
3. 100

instead its printing out

1. 100
2. 150
3. 433

How come the for loop computation doesnt work and is there any better way to sort out the elements in the array to make them in descending order?

this is my code here, thanks for any help:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * Write a program to maintain a list of the high scores obtained in a game.  
 * The program should first ask the user how many scores they want to maintain and then repeatedly accept new scores
 * from the user and should add the score to the list of high scores (in the appropriate position) if it is higher than any of the existing high scores.
 *   You must include the following functions:

    -initialiseHighScores () which sets all high scores to zero.

    -printHighScores() which prints the high scores in the format: 
        “The high scores are 345, 300, 234”, for all exisiting high scores in the list (remember that sometimes it won’t be full).

    -higherThan() which takes the high scores and a new score and returns whether the passed score is higher than any of those in the high score list.

    -insertScore() which takes the current high score list  and a new score and updates it by inserting the new score at the appropriate position in the list
 */
public class HighScores {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many values would you like to set the High Score list too?:");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        int[] zeroSet = {};
        int[] setScores = intialisingHighScores(userInput, zeroSet);
        System.out.println("Now Enter the high scores you wish to display:");
        int[] highScores = printHighScores(setScores, userInput);
        System.out.println("The high scores are:");

        for (int i = 0; i <= (userInput-1); i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + highScores[i]);
        }
    }
    public static int[] intialisingHighScores(int userInput, int[] zeroSet){
        zeroSet = new int [userInput];
        for (int index = 0; index <= (userInput-1); index++)
        {
            zeroSet[index] = 0;
        }

        return zeroSet;
    }
    public static int[] printHighScores(int[] setScores, int userInput) {
        Scanner inputNo = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] setScore = {};
        for (int i = 0; i <= (userInput-1); i++)
        {
            int scores = inputNo.nextInt();
            if(scores<0){
                System.out.println("No player can be that bad, please enter positive high scores only");
                scores = inputNo.nextInt();
                setScores[i] = scores;
            }
            else {
                setScores[i] = scores;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i >= (userInput-1); i++){
            for (int n = 0; n <= (userInput-1); n++){
                if (setScore[i] < setScore[n]){
                    int saveNo = 0;
                    for (int p = (userInput-1); p >= 0; p--){
                        setScore[i] = saveNo;
                        setScore[p] = setScore[p+1];
                    }
                    setScore[userInput-1] = saveNo;
                }
            }
        }
        return setScores;
    }
    public static int[] higherThan(int[] printHighScores, int[] setScores){
        return setScores;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe start with this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Why Don't use Arrays.sort and pass it Comparator to sort in descending order

Comment: ah thank you ill have a look at that, my lecturer never touched upon that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for Integer:

```
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Or you can use `Arrays.sort(array);` and then reverse it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++){
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: essentially its not a reverse order thing, i just want to have it to so it sets the numbers in the array to be descending, when there is a random assortment of numbers in the array.

so 

99
151
77
101

will be output as:

150
101
99
77

Comment: @GregPenrose `sort` normaly sorts ascending. `Collections.reverseOrder()` means, that the comparator reverses the order to descending.

Comment: i noticed that reading the oracle doc but how do i use comparators, we havent touched upon those in our lectures?

Comment: @GregPenrose If you can use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, then you don't have to care about comparators, because there is already a suitable one.

Comment: I would use Integer instead of int.